# A way to avoid Apache Alias path to include HTML resources like CSS

Tags: php, html, apache, mod-rewrite

Here comes a question because my current solution is not really satisfying me for the following problem:

I have an own PHP Framework with MVC pattern in development. And my Router works perfect and all but I have one question I could not find a solution for.

Well I route every incoming request to index.php file which is located in the base-path of my framework. Ofcourse it is no problem to work with relative paths when including css such as:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/include/css/style.css" />
```

This works perfect in the browser. Ofcourse it does not matter what I enter in the URL because every request gets redirected as stated above to the index to make a reasonable routing possible.

However when my url contains multiple slashes which look like subfolders, for example: "/manual/details/1_2" then I get a normal routing process but the browser cannot find the css file unless I add "../" for each "/" in my url to map backwards to my base-path.

For example for the above URL this would work instead:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../style/include/css/style.css" />
```

My curent solution:

I wrote a PHP function in my Routing class that determines the required amount of "../" pattern and I always cast the function before implementing a resource to build the exact 
path at any time.

Example:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?=Router::getInstance()->getSubdirectoryPrefix()?>style/include/css/style.css" />
```

Needless to say that this is very unhandy and also sucks if you forget to place that function. If your route ever changes or you forget that you are in a subdirectory you will wonder why your resource could not be found.

I also know about putting an alias such as Alias /public style/ in my Virtual-Host configuration of Apache but I want to find another - project and PHP internal way without having an unhandy crap such as pasting the alias function all the time and without setting up a virtual-host option so the framework can stay lightweight and does not require any nasty external options like modifying Virtual-Host.

I'd love to hear your solutions, best would be .htacces - oh and by talking over it I leave my .htaccess code here aswell:

```
RewriteEngine On

Options -Indexes

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
```

Thanks in advance for your help~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use **absolute** paths instead of **relative** paths for your html links (css, javascript, images, etc).

For example:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/style/include/css/style.css" />
```

The leading slash (before `style`) means to begin from document root folder, then go into `style` folder, and so on...  (you may have another prefixed directory if it's not in root folder)

You had some problems because some of your rules can create virtual directories (e.g: `http://domain.com/some/directory/subdirectory/etc/`).

Also, in your htaccess, it wouldn't hurt to use a leading slash (or a `RewriteBase`)

```
Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule .* /index.php [L]
```

or (both are the same)

```
Options -Indexes

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
```

Comment: Lol this was way too easy...Thanks alot this worked like a charm!