# .htaccess for friendly URL

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, friendly-url

I want to make a friendly URL for one of my project. Currently my URL is `http://example.com/profile.php?user=someprofile` and I want to make it `http://example.com/someprofile`. I tried the below htaccess but my CSS and image files are not loading.

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond $1 !^(profile\.php|assets|editor|css|js|scripts|images|img|media|xml|user_guide|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)
RewriteRule ^g/([^/\.]+)/?$ profile.php?user=$1 [L]
<Files profile>
    ForceType application/x-httpd-php
</Files>
```

How do I achieve this?

Comment: Why do you have `^g/` in your pattern?

Comment: Your files directive is irrelevant. You're not dealing with files, you're dealing with virtual urls.

Comment: Probably related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27744603/css-js-and-images-do-not-display-with-pretty-url

Comment: @anubhava ^g/ gives me a result like http://example.com/g/someprofile, I picked this up from another answer.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like an issue with relative/absolute URLs. Since you added a `/g/` to the beginning of your URL's, that changed the relative URI base so all your relative links will be broken. You need to either change your links to absolute links or add a relative URI base to the header of your pages:

```
<base href="/" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Have your .htaccess as this:

```
RewriteEngine on

# If the request is not for a valid directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# If the request is not for a valid file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ profile.php?user=$1 [L,QSA]
```

**css/js/images path issue:**
It is better to  use absolute path in your css, js, images files rather than a relative one. Which means you have to make sure path of these files start either with `http://` or a slash `/`.

**Otherwise** you can try adding this in the `<head>` section of your page's HTML: `<base href="/" />` so that every relative URL is resolved from that URL and not the current page's URL.