# RewriteRule for nicer URL

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to redirect queries like

```
www.example.com/mysite/post/3/title-of-the-post
```

to

```
www.example.com/mysite/display.php?id=3
```

by setting a `.htaccess` file at the root of `www.example.com/mysite/`. I tried :

```
.htaccess file
---------------

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^post/([0-9]+)/* index.php?id=$1 [L]
```

Why doesn't this work? **How to set up a RewriteRule in this situation?** Do I need to add more lines than this single line in .htaccess ?

Comment: Do you have `mod_rewrite` enabled in your server? And I think you're missing a `.` and `$` in your rule, try `RewriteRule ^post/([0-9]+)/.*$ index.php?id=$1 [L]`

Comment: yes @IkoTikashi :  `a2enmod rewrite` =>  `Module rewrite already enabled`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the `*` (which should actually be `.*`) at the end because you're not ending the expression with `$`. So you can do this instead:

```
RewriteRule ^post/([0-9]+)/ index.php?id=$1 [L]
```

If you want to close the expression, then use this:

```
RewriteRule ^post/([0-9]+)/.*$ index.php?id=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Thanks, it nearly works (I had to add `RewriteEngine On` that was missing) : the page is now loaded, but now the CSS and JS files are not found, because they are searched in `http://www.example.com/mysite/post/3/css/mysite.css` ;) instead of `http://www.example.com/mysite/css/mysite.css`... How to allow CSS, JS files to go to the good location?

Comment: Same problem @MikeAnthony for JS files, etc. : they are searched in `example.com/mysite/post/3/blah.js`  instead of `example.com/mysite/blah.js`. How to solve this problem?

Comment: @Basj See the tag info for [mod-rewrite](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/mod-rewrite/info). It links to [this common question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27744603/css-js-and-images-do-not-display-with-pretty-url), which will answer that question.

Comment: You need to make sure that your files are being referenced properly. So your reference for the stylesheet should be: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/mysite/css/mysite.css">`. Alternatively, you should set a base tag: `<base href="/mysite/">` and leave everything else as is.

Comment: @MikeAnthony isn't there another solution than hardcoding each thing like `/mysite/css/mysite.css` (now I have `css/mysite.css`)... Imagine one day `/mysite/` becomes `/blah/`, then I have to change everything

Comment: As I said, you can use a `base` tag. See [this](http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/articles/quick-tip-set-relative-urls-with-the-base-tag--cms-21399) for more information.