# CSS is not working in my CodeIgniter Project, But why?

Tags: css, .htaccess, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-url

```
My Project Directory at Server address is : ci.xyz.com/ci/h/

I used on my codeigniter project:

$config['base_url'] = './';
$config['index_page'] = '';//index.php
```

Route as:

```
$route['default_controller'] = "home/index/";
```

HtAccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteBase /ci/h/
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

```
<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
   ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

When the index function of home (from route default controller) is loaded then all resources is working. But when I click to a link to (such as home/aboutus) then the resources is not working only display text. I used as link echo base_url('home/aboutus'); and for resoureces echo base_url('assets/theme/css/style.css');

What is my wrong ? Could you suggest me about my problem ?

Comment: I don't know enough about codeigniter to judge if the problem outlined in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27744603/css-js-and-images-do-not-display-with-pretty-url) is a problem here, but you could read it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

I’d recommend using a sub domain e.g http://ci.xyz.com then 
Set the $route['default_controller'] = "home/index/"; to **$route['default_controller'] = "home";**

Open application/config/config.php and set your base_url as **$config['base_url'] = 'http://ci.xyz.com/';** // Do not forget the forward slash at the end
Then change your ROOT/.htaccess to

```html
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

To link to your CSS files in ROOT/assets folder just use something like assets/theme/css/style.css