# htaccess - Need help writing the correct rule

Tags: php, .htaccess

I'm using [SimpleMVCFramework](http://simplemvcframework.com/)

All my routes are working fine, based on the default htaccess file:

```
Options -Indexes

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    Options -Indexes

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /mpl/servicos/smvcf/

    # Force to exclude the trailing slash
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.*)/$
    RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ $1 [R=307,L]

    # Allow any files or directories that exist to be displayed directly
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1 [QSA,L]

</IfModule>
```

I have a route that expects an id:
http://localhost/mpl/servicos/smvcf/detalhe/37343

But I need the URL the user sees to be friendly as:
http://localhost/mpl/servicos/smvcf/mercedes_benz-a-a_220_cdi_auto-37343.html

I thought something like this would work, but I get a 404:

```
RewriteRule ([^/]+)-([^/]+)-([^/]+)-([^/]+).html detalhe/$4
```

Please help.

Comment: Why not using a static rule in this case ? Such as `RewriteRule ^mercedes_benz-a-a_220_cdi_auto-37343\.html$ detalhe/37343 [L]`. Also, make sure to put your rule **above** the last one (otherwise, it won't never be executed)

Comment: RewriteRule ([^/]+)-([0-9]+).html detalhe/$4

Comment: Can't Justin, that user friendly URL will be generated dynamically so I don't know what it will look like and can't match every case. I just need to pass the final ID before the html extension to the route.

Comment: Jurgis, I get a 404 with your rule.

Answer (score 0):

The user sees the pretty url, but you are not interested in what the seo-title is. What you are interested in is the number that is hidden in it. As the number is in the very back of the pretty url, let's just match on that:

```
RewriteRule ^[^/]+-([0-9]+)\.html detalhe/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Still no glory.
I'm far from an expert on htaccess, but I think all your inputs are ok. Maybe it has something to do with the framework configuration. I've asked for help on the support forum but no answers yet.
With your example, I can access http://localhost/mpl/servicos/smvcf/detalhe/37343 but all the defined CSS and javascript files aren't loaded. If I access the friendly URLI get a 404 plus the CSS and JS aren't loaded.

Comment: See [the info section of the mod_rewrite tag](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/mod-rewrite/info), specifically [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27744603/css-js-and-images-do-not-display-with-pretty-url).

Comment: That's not the case. With and without your rule, the CSS and JS are all defined with absolute paths :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to use another rewrite that will not be routed through the default MVC route index.php then you need to make sure you place your new rewrite before those rules. Also that folder you are redirecting to will need to have a index PHP file to do something as well.

```
Options -Indexes

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /mpl/servicos/smvcf/

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.+)-([0-9]+)\.html detalhe/$2 [L]

    # Force to exclude the trailing slash
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.*)/$
    RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ $1 [R=307,L]

    # Allow any files or directories that exist to be displayed directly
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1 [QSA,L]

</IfModule>
```

Comment: Hi! My index.php in the folder /mpl/servicos/smvcf/ is the default MVC route. The routes are defined like:
//define routes
Router::any('/marcas', '\controllers\marcas@index');
Router::any('/modelos/(:any)', '\controllers\modelos@index');
Router::any('/versoes/(:any)', '\controllers\versoes@index');
Router::any('/detalhe/(:any)', '\controllers\detalhe@index');

What I need is when a user accesses http://localhost/mpl/servicos/smvcf/mercedes_benz-a-a_220_cdi_auto-37343.html it should go to http://localhost/mpl/servicos/smvcf/detalhe/37343 and then the MVC index should do it's thing right?

Comment: I get a No routes found with your example because it redirects to http://localhost/mpl/servicos/smvcf/detalhe but with no ID at the end...

Comment: Hi Panama Jack. Still No routes found. I think I'll have to go with a custom router for this.