# How do I rewrite the phpbb directory to another directory?

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, joomla, phpbb3

I have phpbb in a directory of my joomla install which also happens to be inside a directory on the root (so that's `me.domain.com/joomla/phpbb`). I have successfully been able to rewrite joomla's directory to the root of a parked domain (`me.domain.com/joomla/ --> domain2.com/` ) but when every I go to `domain2.com/forum` non of the style sheets work but `domain2.com/joomla/forum` works fine. Any help please?

### Edit

I found that the css files werent being called properly. The page was calling from `domain2.com/styles/` instead of from `domain2.com/forum/styles/`

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS, JS and images do not display with pretty url](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27744603/css-js-and-images-do-not-display-with-pretty-url)

Comment: They are linked by {T_THEME_PATH}, which is not returning the correct path