# Can`t set a base url of my sub domain

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have a sub domain and use url rewrite conditions with .htaccess file,

I did write this code on top of my header file to reference the base url for .htaccess to work :

```
<base href="http://www.eduzone.esy.es/">

</head>
```

But the files are not loaded and the site is not working, no css files loaded, can`t visit any link.

I tried searching for solutions but still couldnt resolve. Please help.

Comment: Please share the content of your `.htaccess` file, as well as some `<a href="{something}">` tags so we can get some insight into the issue you're facing.

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS, JS and images do not display with pretty url](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27744603/css-js-and-images-do-not-display-with-pretty-url)