# .htaccess setting for local pathing and development

Tags: .htaccess, directory, root

My initial feeling is this can be done with .htaccess, but if there is another/better way I'm open to it.

I'll try and explain what I'm doing and want.

I am developing a site (newsite.com), to replace currentsite.com.

There is already a site up an currentsite.com domain.

I figured I'll try and develop on my personal domain, until tested ready to launch, and move things over, replacing current site.com

So I have personalsite.com (my personal domain)..and I created a directory called  staging.newsite.com

So the full URL is http://www.personalsite.com/staging.newsite.com.

However, I am having trouble pathing to CSS and JS files with this set up.

In the header file I load my css as so:

```
<link href="_includes/css/default.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Doing this:

```
<link href="/_includes/css/default.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

makes it point to _root of www.personalsite.com to look for includes folder.

which seems to work fine when I go:
http://www.personalsite.com/staging.newsite.com

but when I go to a content page on the staging.newsite.com, like:
(for example)
http://www.personalsite.com/staging.newsite.com/sub-dir1/sub-dir2/contentpage.php

The CSS breaks..

Is there a way to set this up so http://www.personalsite.com/staging.newsite.com is seen as the root directory for this staging.newsite.com?  Or some other way to set it up for easier developing and then will be a simple upload to its final domain (without the need for the .htaccess rules?)

I tried this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^staging\.newsite\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://staging.newsite.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

but that re-directs the MAIN personalsite.com to http://www.staging.newsite.com  (which of course is just a subdirectory of personal.com for development purposes..etc)

update: 08.11.2015
edit: This is NOT a vanity URL re-write question.. please treat it as such, and do not post it as a duplicate of that topic.  If you feel it IS the same, explain why and how the same solution applies, out of context links do nothing for anyone.

update: 08.11.2015
I believe what I am looking for/to do is referred to as: "normalizing" the sub-domain/directory? (new term for me, so I'll search on that as well)

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS, JS and images do not display with pretty url](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27744603/css-js-and-images-do-not-display-with-pretty-url)

Comment: thanks.. but I'm not looking to do vanity URLS

Although I can try adding int he Rewrite Base part they mention (that is off topic for that thread)

Comment: I dupe-voted it, because the answer I would give for this question would be exactly the same answer I gave to that question. Your problem is that your css breaks, because it tries to search your css in the wrong place. You either need to make your url's absolute, or at least relative to the root of your website, or you need to specify what the base is on which the absolute url's will be calculated. This is where `<base>` comes in. You would use `<base href="/staging.newsite.com/">`.