# Htaccess Rewriting URL error

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, redirect

I want to rewrite URL using mod_rewrite in Apache server.

Specifically I want to rewrite URLs of the following form - mywebsite.com/web/ger/int/sb/index.html into mywebsite.com/gerintsb/

In the case of above URL ger, int, sb are appended together to form the shorter URL. I have many such URLs to be shortened.

I used the following RewriteRule in my .htaccess file inside the "web" folder in my server-

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)([a-z]+)([a-z]+)$    web/$1/$2/$3/index.html    [NC,L]
```

But my rule is not working. I am getting an object not found error.

Can someone troubleshoot?

Comment: Do you want only this URL to be rewritten or you have many such URLs?

Comment: I have many such urls. Such as web/fr/int/mp, web/ger/int/rt ... etc. I edited  my question to make it more clear :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[a-z]+` is greedy. It will consume the entire string. The second two capture groups will not catch anything. If a slash is at the end of the path your rule will not match.

You can only do this if you know the possible values of the path segments, or if the path segments have a fixed width:

```
RewriteRule ^(ger|fr)(int|float)(sb|mp|rt)/?$ web/$1/$2/$3/index.html [L]
```

or:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{3})([a-z]{3})([a-z]{2})/?$ web/$1/$2/$3/index.html [L]
```

Comment: This is the closest I can find. I will make this the answer but I have a doubt as well. When i use these mod_rewrite all my CSS links, Images .etc will break if I am using relative links. So I had to change the relative links to absolute links throughout my landing pages. Any idea how to overcome it?

Comment: See [this page](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/mod-rewrite/info) and [this Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27744603/css-js-and-images-do-not-display-with-pretty-url) in particular.